# Как избежать warning-а в range based for loop?

Tags: gcc, c++

Начал экспериментировать с новым стандартом C++ и столкнулся с проблемой.
У меня есть класс, который предоставляет числовой диапазон, по которому
можно итерироваться. Он позволяет цикл вида

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

заменить на

```
for (int i: range(N)) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Этот код прекрасно работает, но если мы хотим просто повторить действие несколько раз:

```
for (int i: range(N)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

то компилятор (g++-4.6) выдает предупреждение

> warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]

при этом классический цикл for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) компилируется прекрасно.
У меня возник вопрос - это нормальное поведение или это баг g++?
Ведь фактически переменная i используется.
Можно ли как-нибудь отключить это предупреждение?
-Wno-unused-variable не предлагать.

UPD:
Почитал стандарт, там написано:

The range-based for statement

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = ( expression );
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr, __end = end-expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin )
    {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

так что действительно в моем случае переменная i - неиспользуемая.

Comment: Испокон веку для этого использовался модификатор volatile.
Как оно в новых модных стандартах — хузны; может, еще какую конструкцию придумали.

Comment: По-моему, ключевое слово `volatile` тут вообще не в кассу.

Comment: испокон веку для этого использовался UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( i ), но собственно только для того, чтобы впоследствии заменить это дело на что-то более подходящее, о чем уже сказал @1101_debian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение, ведь, как вы верно заметили, переменная i не используется, а в классическом варианте переменная используется, ибо она инкрементируется.

Answer (score 4):

Использовать другой цикл. Этот вид цикла предназначен для прохода по коллекциям, а вы его используете немного не по назначению.

Answer (score 1):

если нужно, то как-то так:

```
for (int i: range(N)) {
#ifdef OMG
  doAnything(i);
#else
  (void)i;
  doSomething();
#endif
}
```